# RDP into multiple win 10 computers from c#

Tags: c#, windows-10, rdp

I am attempting to login into multiple win 10 computers via rdp from a list of computer names then reboot them. From my best knowledge rdp is the way to do this. I am in the beginning stages and I am not able to even connect one machine.

I have attempted and tested code from every resource I could find. I have tested the multiple Microsoft RDP Client Control versions and verified I have version 10 on my Windows 10 Machine. Below is the code I have so far.

```
 private void startBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        try
        {
            dmain = @"MGROUPNET\";
            lines = listBox.Lines;
            Server = lines[0];

            dmain = dmain + nUser;

            //Testing to verify correct details
            usernameLabel.Text = dmain;
            passLabel.Text = nPass;
            serverLabel.Text = Server;

            rdp1.Server = Server;
            rdp1.UserName = dmain;
            rdp1.AdvancedSettings9.NegotiateSecurityLayer = true;
            rdp1.AdvancedSettings8.ClearTextPassword = nPass;

            rdp1.Connect();

            connectLabel.Text = this.rdp1.Connected.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Disconnecting: " + Ex);
        }
    }
```

After this code, I get a connection status of 2. This then changes to 0 without displaying anything. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use [shutdown.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/shutdown.html) with `/m \\Computername /r` Parameter to reboot remotely?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use PsExec instead of RDP. You can download it from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec

Now, all you have to do is just open a cmd window with your c# program with the following command:
 `psexec_path \\target_IPv4 -u local_username -p password shutdown.exe -t 0 -r`

If connection is succeed, the device will try restart with the specified user credentials. Make sure that the user has the required permissions to do this (e.g. if you are in a domain).

**I have to notice that the connection connection is not secured. Use PsExec v2.1 at least to encrypt your connection.**

Comment: Why psexec over [psshutdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psshutdown)?

Comment: I didn't know PsShutdown. Thanks you, that exactly what Evan's looking for. I'll update my answer soon.

Comment: You're welcome. There is also "shutdown.exe" (mentioned in comment to question). It should also work. I haven't figured out, what the differences / benefits / drawbacks between those two are. Personally, I'd try shutdown.exe first, then psshutdown. If both don't work I'd probably be searching for a powershell script.